# A question on Lewis dot structures

Tags: lewis-structure

[image]

In the image shown is a carboxylate ion, I don't understand why we draw 6 electrons on the oxygen and say it has a formal negative charge on it instead of putting 5 dots to represent it used one of its valence electrons? Like is it wrong to put an odd number of electrons on the atom in a Lewis dot structure, or is there some other reason?

Comment: It is the other way around: we are told that it has a negative charge on it, hence we draw 6 electrons instead of 5.

Comment: For future reference: consider to familiarize yourself with programs to draw chemical formulae ([a comparison of some](https://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/index.html)).  If your school does not offer to participate in a campus license, there are some versions with reduced functionality (compared to the full program), e.g., [ChemDraw JS](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#), or [Marvin JS](https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/demo.html) I used for the answer below running from any web browser allowing JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from acetic acid, there is single bond between oxygen and hydrogen because each of them contribute a single electron:

[image]

When the acid donates this proton, *both* electrons remain on the more electronegative atom (in the Pauling scale, oxygen: 3.44, hydrogen 2.20, [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity)).  Thus, this totals to six.

Note, when drawing structure formulae with electrons and electron pairs, do not confuse the dash *indicating the charge*, with the dash to represent *two electrons*.